# How show a filtered version of my model?

Tags: ember.js

My Ember app automatically show a list of tasks. The model are populated like this:

```
model: function(){
    return this.store.find('task');
}
```

My question is, how i can show a filtered version of this model in view?

If i create a route to this? tasks/completed?

**Updating:**

I created a route:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('tasks', function(){
    this.resource('task', { path:'/:task_id' }, function(){
      this.route('edit');
    });
    this.route('create');
    this.route('completed');
  });
});
```

Then i call:

```
App.TasksCompletedRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  // What i have to put here to show only completed tasks?
});
```

This is my project: https://github.com/fernandoperigolo/ember-crud-todo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `filteredContent` property, and set with all the tasks in the TasksRoute, and with just the completed tasks in `TasksCompleted`. Like the following:

Routes:

```
App.TasksRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.find('task');
  },
  setupController: function(controller, tasks) {
    controller.set('filteredContent', tasks);
  },
  actions:{
    check:function(task){
      task.set('done', true);
      task.save();
    },
    uncheck:function(task){
      task.set('done', false);
      task.save();
    }
  }
});

App.TasksCompletedRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    this.controllerFor('tasks').set('filteredContent', this.modelFor('tasks').filterBy('done', true));
  }
});
```

So in your tasks template use the `filteredContent` instead of `controller`:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="tasks">
    {{#link-to "tasks.create"}} Add task {{/link-to}}

    <h2>Task List:</h2>
    <ul>
      {{#each task in filteredContent}}
        <li>
          {{#if task.done}}
            <button {{action "uncheck" task}}>Uncheck</button>
          {{else}}
            <button {{action "check" task}}>Check</button>
          {{/if}}
          {{#link-to "task" task}}{{task.title}}{{/link-to}}
        </li>
      {{else}}
        <li>no tasks… :(</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, the github repo helped a lot. I updated the answer please give a look

Comment: I look and re-look it. I understand and apply your suggestion. It make all sense, but just no works, sadly.

The app dont return errors. I think we miss something.

Comment: Updated project git hub repo.

Comment: I refectory my code using your suggestion and everything are working now. I needed to create a `TasksAllRoute`. Now, i need to understand what is setup controller and how it works. Thanks for all.